# Ruby on Rails new instance within different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm sure this is easy but I can't figure it out

I have basically two scaffolds: Envelope and Transaction.
I can go into the transaction views and make a new transaction like normal but what I want is to be able to make a new transaction within the Show view of envelopes.

is this possible?

I've tried rendering the transaction form in the Envelope show. can't get that to work. Now I'm trying to just link to the transaction controller but I can't get this to work either.

```
<p>
  <h3>New Transaction</h3>
  <%= link_to("New Transaction", :controller => :transactions, :action => :new, envelope_id => @envelope.id) %>
</p>
```

Update:

It occured to me that what I'm trying to do is analogous to a blog post and comment, where the comment form is directly linked to and located on the specific post you want to attach your comment to. So I looked up some code on how to do that and came up with this on my show envelope page:

```
<p>
  <h3>New Transaction</h3>
  <%= form_for [@envelope, @envelope.transactions.build] do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.text_field :cash %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit "Create" %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Which is awesome because now the page loads, but when I try to do a save I get this error:

NoMethodError in TransactionsController#create
undefined method `transaction_url' for #TransactionsController:0x3c35e38

```
Extracted source (around line #31):        
29    respond_to do |format|
30      if @transaction.save
31        format.html { redirect_to @transaction, notice: 'Transaction was successfully created.' }
32        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @transaction }
33      else
34        format.html { render :new }
```

So I don't think its actually making the Transaction item and putting it in the database.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What you're looking for is called nested forms. You can also look into something like http://activeadmin.info/ or https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin to help you out (think scaffolding on steroids)

Comment: Thanks I'll look that over, I eventually found a solution by following this tutorial and starting over, thanks! [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaL9ul17kx0)